# Heroku commands on Cygwin hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, cygwin

I am trying to use `Heroku` commands on `Cygwin` but they seem to not do anything, but hang.

I installed the `Heroku toolbelt for Windows`.

Doing the `$ heroku version` gives me `heroku/toolbelt/3.10.5 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3`.

But whenever I try a `$ heroku login` or `$ heroku login` it just hangs and does nothing.

I setup a Heroku remote in one of my Github repo folders and tried to `heroku push master` but it prompts me for my password, and I type it in, but gives me this message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Help! Has anyone successfully used `Heroku` on `Cygwin`?

Comment: Nothing works properly with cygwin, in my experience. If you have to use Windows, consider http://rubyinstaller.org/ (or a VM with Ubuntu) - you'll be a lot happier. (I developed Rails in Windows for over 5 years before I wised up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like heroku is trying to log in with your ssh key, which isn't added to your account. Ensure that you've added your public key to your heroku account (if you log in, go to account, add the ssh *public* key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)). [this](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) might help you out as well.

Comment: @AdamRGrey Just added the `SSH public key` to my Heroku account. And that fixed my pushing to heroku master problem! Thanks. But, on a side note, whenever I try to do `heroku login` it just hangs and doesn't do anything, any idea for that?

Comment: @TheNomad sure you're welcome, and for hanging heroku login, sadly, I have no idea.